# 429 Too Many Requests when use Openstreetmap in Android app but it is not

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I try to use openstreetmap in my android app. But when start the app, it just shows a grid without data. This is the log:

```
W/ootm.MapTileDownloader: Problem downloading MapTile: /13/4090/2721 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
I/System.out: Thread-3632(ApacheHTTPLog):isSBSettingEnabled false
    Thread-3632(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
    Thread-3632(ApacheHTTPLog):getDebugLevel 0x4f4c
    Thread-3632(ApacheHTTPLog):Smart Bonding Setting is false
    Thread-3632(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Setting is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false, DEBUG_LEVEL (1-LOW, 2-MID, 3-HIGH) is 1
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: netid=0; mark=0
```

It indicates that "Too many requests", but I just run in my app.
What is problem?

Comment: what tile source?

Comment: mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);

Comment: Is that you looking for?

Comment: public static final OnlineTileSourceBase DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE = MAPNIK

Comment: Is your app setting a custom UserAgent string, or is it just using the default?

See also https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

Comment: It solved my problem. @HartmutHolzgraefe thank you